# Modification in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to get an output xml from a given xml using xslt.The output xml will have some elements to be added in the the given xml.But I am not getting the required output.

I have an input xml like:

```
  <Response xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/"  xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/">
    <out xmlns="">
        <Number xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/">Desc1</Number>
        <Address xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc2</Address>
        <Records xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc3</Records>
    </out>
</Response>
```

I want an output xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:Reqeust xmlns:abc="http://www.nnn.com/bnm"
xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/" xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/" >
    <abc:Tray>
        <abc:Remote>
            <abc:ID>ID1</abc:ID>
            <abc:Distance>Always</abc:Distance>
        </abc:Remote>
        <abc:Time>
            1100-01-01T01:01:01+05:30
        </abc:Time>
        <abc:AreaMap />
    </abc:Tray>
    <abc:Area>
        <abc:Get>
            <abc:Fault>Token1</abc:Fault>
        </abc:Get>
        <Response xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/"  xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/">
            <out xmlns="">
                <Number xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/">Desc1</Number>
                <Address xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc2</Address>
                <Records xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc3</Records>
            </out>
        </Response>
    </abc:Area>
</abc:Reqeust>
```

I am using the xslt:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:abc="http://www.nnn.com/bnm"
xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/" xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/" >
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <abc:Request>
            <abc:Tray>
                <abc:Remote>
                    <abc:ID>ID1</abc:ID>
                    <abc:Distance>Always</abc:Distance>
                </abc:Remote>
                <abc:Time>
                    1100-01-01T01:01:01+05:30
                </abc:Time>
                <abc:AreaMap />
            </abc:Tray>
            <abc:Area>
                <abc:Get>
                    <abc:Fault>Token1</abc:Fault>
                </abc:Get>
                <Response>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </Response>
            </abc:Area>
        </abc:Request>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I am not getting the required output.
What changes should I make in the xslt to get the required output xml?

Answer (score 0):

In xslt-1.0 you have always to use a **namespace prefix** to access a name which belongs to an namespace.
The **Response** element in your input XML belongs to the default namespace `xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/"`.
You have already added this namespace as `xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/`.

Therefore change your template for Response form:

```
<xsl:template match="Response">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Response">
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc:Request xmlns:abc="http://www.nnn.com/bnm" xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.abc/max/" xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/">
    <abc:Tray>
        <abc:Remote>
            <abc:ID>ID1</abc:ID>
            <abc:Distance>Always</abc:Distance>
        </abc:Remote>
        <abc:Time>
            1100-01-01T01:01:01+05:30
        </abc:Time>
        <abc:AreaMap/>
    </abc:Tray>
    <abc:Area>
        <abc:Get>
            <abc:Fault>Token1</abc:Fault>
        </abc:Get>
        <Response>
            <out xmlns="">
                <Number xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max/">Desc1</Number>
                <Address xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc2</Address>
                <Records xmlns="http://xyz.abc/max">Desc3</Records>
            </out>
        </Response>
    </abc:Area>
</abc:Request>
```